# Recursively Add to a List in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm working on program in Scheme that reads a data file line-by-line and then adds each line to a list. Currently, I can open the file with a function defined as (open-file fileName), where the variable fileName is a stored value of the file's name. There is also a helper function that looks at each line. The functions are as follows:

```
(define (open-file fileName)
  (let ((port (open-input-file fileName)))
    (open-file-helper port)
    (close-input-port port)
    'done
  )
)

(define (open-file-helper port)
      (let ((stuff (read-line port)))
        (if (eof-object? stuff)
        'done
        (begin (display (str-split stuff)) (newline)
               (append (list (str-split stuff)) (print-file-helper port))
               (display list) (newline)
        )
        )
      )
    )
```

With the current functions, I cannot append all of my lines to the list. What am I missing here?

Comment: What Scheme version are you using? In Racket, you can use [`file->lines`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffile..rkt%29._file-~3elines%29%29).

Comment: I've marked this question as duplicate, the linked post gives several options that should work on your Scheme flavor.

Comment: Regarding your solution, you need to check your understanding of recursion and how Scheme returns a value. The line with the `append` is doing nothing at all, it just creates a list that gets discarded immediately, because you're not returning it as the result of the recursion. And you should use `cons` to add an element to the head of a list. And you're displaying the built-in procedure called `list`, _not_ the list that you're trying to build.